# Rearrange a dataframe / matrix into pattern

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matrix

I have a matrix of 0s and 1s and I want to arrange the matrix in a way that rows with value 1 in same column appear together.

For example, if i create a matrix using `A = np.random.randint(2,size=(100, 1000),dtype=np.int8)` 
It will generate a random matrix of 0 and 1 and I will further reduce the number of 1 in the matrix. Now i want to rearrange the matrix so that if i visualize 1 with yellow and 0 with purple, this is how the output should look like.

Think of the matrix where a row is a person_id and columns are one hot encoded where every column represents something that the person owns. So I want to arrange this in a way that person who own similar items appear together. So arrange both rows and columns so visualizing it will look like the image attached.

One solution is to basically sort row order based on row sum and then column order based on column sum but I am looking for something which can guarantee correct results like this.
Side note, the size of the matrix will be as high as 200k*300k
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I am missunderstanding the problem, but would be enough to sort it? The thing is, if your matrix is:

```
   1 1 1
A= 0 0 0
   0 1 0
   1 0 1
```

you have two valid depending if you prioritize the first or second column:

```
    1 1 1                   1 1 1
A1= 1 0 1               A2= 0 1 0
    0 1 0                   1 0 1
    0 0 0                   0 0 0
```

I will assume that you want to prioritize the 1st, then if equal the 2nd, then the 3rd... and so on. Given that, you can sort the dataframe by all columns:

`df.sort_values(by=df.columns.tolist(),ascending=False,inplace = True)`

If I missunderstood the problem (can be) just tell me :)

Comment: yeah something like this where I can rearrange the order of rows and columns to bring similar things together